# Why are Google and AOL results different?

Tags: google, search-engines

AOL is powered by Google but I am seeing different results if I use the same search terms in each one. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is probably using personalized search and/or geolocation. AOL is not.

Answer (score 1):

AOL's search says enhanced by google, not that it uses the same google algorithm. AOL probably pays google for access to a database with search results and some of google's search features. They probably don't get access to google's current algorithm.